# Bidirectional LSTM in encoder decoder model running out of memory on training

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, lstm

```
latent_dim = 500
embedding_dim = 256
# Encoder 
encoder_inputs = Input(shape=(max_eng_len,)) 
enc_emb = Embedding(x_voc_size, embedding_dim,trainable=True)(encoder_inputs) 
 
#LSTM 1 
encoder_lstm1 = Bidirectional(LSTM(latent_dim,return_sequences=True,return_state=True))
encoder_output1, forw_state_h, forw_state_c, back_state_h, back_state_c = encoder_lstm1(enc_emb)
 
final_enc_h = Concatenate()([forw_state_h,back_state_h])
final_enc_c = Concatenate()([forw_state_c,back_state_c])
 
encoder_states =[final_enc_h, final_enc_c]
 
# Decoder
decoder_inputs = Input(shape=(None,)) 
dec_emb_layer = Embedding(y_voc_size, embedding_dim,trainable=True) 
dec_emb = dec_emb_layer(decoder_inputs) 
 
#LSTM using encoder_states as initial state
decoder_lstm = LSTM(latent_dim*2, return_sequences=True, return_state=True) 
decoder_outputs,decoder_fwd_state, decoder_back_state = decoder_lstm(dec_emb,initial_state=encoder_states) 
 
#from tensorflow.keras.layers import Attention
#Attention Layer
attention_layer = AttentionLayer()
attn_res, attn_weight = attention_layer([encoder_output1, decoder_outputs])
 
# Concat attention output and decoder LSTM output 
decoder_concat_input = Concatenate(axis=-1, name='concat_layer')([decoder_outputs, attn_res])
 
#Dense layer
decoder_dense = TimeDistributed(Dense(y_voc_size, activation='softmax')) 
decoder_outputs = decoder_dense(decoder_concat_input) 
 
# model
model = Model([encoder_inputs, decoder_inputs], decoder_outputs) 
model.summary()
 
# Compile
model.compile(optimizer='rmsprop', loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])

checkpoint = ModelCheckpoint("/content/drive/My Drive/checkpoint.txt", monitor='val_accuracy')
early_stopping = EarlyStopping(monitor='val_accuracy', patience=5)
callbacks_list = [checkpoint, early_stopping]

# Training set
encoder_input_data = X_train
decoder_input_data = Y_train[:,:-1]
decoder_target_data =  Y_train[:,1:]

# devlopment set
encoder_input_test = X_test
decoder_input_test = Y_test[:,:-1]
decoder_target_test=  Y_test[:,1:]
history = model.fit([encoder_input_data, decoder_input_data],decoder_target_data, 
                    epochs=50, 
                    batch_size=64,
                    validation_data = ([encoder_input_test, decoder_input_test],decoder_target_test),
                    callbacks= callbacks_list)
```

x_voc_size is 45701 and y_voc_size is 84213. Approximately there are 45,000 records. I am getting memory error while training this model on 35GB RAM. Even after reducing the batch size to 25, I am getting the same error. Please suggest how to go about this error.

```
Model: "model"
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                    Output Shape         Param #     Connected to                     
==================================================================================================
input_1 (InputLayer)            [(None, 5515)]       0                                            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
embedding (Embedding)           (None, 5515, 256)    11699456    input_1[0][0]                    
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
input_2 (InputLayer)            [(None, None)]       0                                            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
bidirectional (Bidirectional)   [(None, 5515, 1000), 3028000     embedding[0][0]                  
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
embedding_1 (Embedding)         (None, None, 256)    21558528    input_2[0][0]                    
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
concatenate (Concatenate)       (None, 1000)         0           bidirectional[0][1]              
                                                                 bidirectional[0][3]              
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
concatenate_1 (Concatenate)     (None, 1000)         0           bidirectional[0][2]              
                                                                 bidirectional[0][4]              
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
lstm_1 (LSTM)                   [(None, None, 1000), 5028000     embedding_1[0][0]                
                                                                 concatenate[0][0]                
                                                                 concatenate_1[0][0]              
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
attention_layer (AttentionLayer ((None, None, 1000), 2001000     bidirectional[0][0]              
                                                                 lstm_1[0][0]                     
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
concat_layer (Concatenate)      (None, None, 2000)   0           lstm_1[0][0]                     
                                                                 attention_layer[0][0]            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
time_distributed (TimeDistribut (None, None, 84213)  168510213   concat_layer[0][0]               
==================================================================================================
Total params: 211,825,197
Trainable params: 211,825,197
Non-trainable params: 0
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
```

EDIT - This is the model's summary. I think the parameters are huge. But how to efficiently reduce the complexity of the model?

Comment: can you print `model.summary()`

Comment: Added model.summary()

Answer (score 0):

That's quite the model and I bet you if we can talk it out a bit we can find something suitable for your use case. To give you an idea of where you stand, you're really going to want a cloud tpu cluster for something that big. I've been through most of the deeplearning ai specializations now and they choose a cloud tpu cluster between 5,000,000 and 13,000,000 parameters. The model you have there is something that would really want to be trained in a bigger corporate data center or national lab environment. In lieu of that though, it would be really good for you to check out transfer learning as large numbers of great models have already been trained in that environment and you could piggyback off them for free. I'd say if you can bring down the number of trainable parameters to something like 3,000,000, you might find something much, much more amenable for your hardware. Please, let's turn this into a conversation so everyone gets to learn. Let me know your thoughts!

Comment: I am working on abstractive text summarization task. I am not sure reducing which parameter won't affect the model's accuracy drastically. Since this is a healthcare data vocabulary size is really huge. Reducing the batch size to 1 trains the model without causing memory error.

Comment: Ok. I perfectly well leave this decision up to you. If the model nerds to be of this size, I just wanted to give you those options is all. I'm not the biggest fan of stochastic gradient descent as it has such an erratic traversal over the loss surface that I worry about it properly converging to a minima. Just as a heads up, I am sure you found in the last few days this trains for a long time, but I'll leave it at that. Post here if you need any more help and I'll do my best to stay on top of it